# Outlook Calendar properties: What does it mean when permissions is empty?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I added a new calendar in my outlook and by right click and choosing properties then permissions tab I have noticed that it is empty. What does this mean, can people look at this calendar? see I'm busy or not?

[image: Outlook Calendar permissions]